# Fibonaccith fibonacci number

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Let $f_n$ denote the $n$th Fibonacci number. A positive integer $n$ is called good if $f_{f_n}$ is divisible by $n$ but $f_n$ is not divisible by $n$.

My question is: how many good numbers are there. I think there are infinity many but I can’t prove it. Thanks!

Anyway this is from a russian book called: All about Fibonacci

Comment: What does it mean to say "$f_{f_n}$ is divisible"?

Comment: Also just to clarify : does the Fibonacci series start $1,1,2,3,5,..$ or $0,1,1,2,3,5,...$? Note that this changes  the indexing, and the question depends on the indexing.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As you believe there are infinitely numbers of the sort you want, perhaps you could write down the first few.  As it stands, the definitions aren't clear (at least, not to me).

Comment: FYI : http://oeis.org/A007570

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $n$ is good. Since $\gcd(f_m,f_n)=f_{\gcd(m,n)}$, we have
$$\gcd(f_{f_{f_n}},f_n)=f_{\gcd(f_{f_n},n)}=f_n,$$
and $$\gcd(f_{f_n},f_n)=f_{\gcd(f_n,n)}<f_n.$$
Therefore, $f_n$ is good. So if there is one good number, there must exist infinitely many good numbers.